# I get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php

```
<?php

    // configuration
    require("../includes/config.php"); 

     render("home_form.php", ["title" => "Log In"]);
?>


  /**
     * Renders template, passing in values.
     */
    function render($template, $values = [])
    {
        // if template exists, render it
        if (file_exists("../templates/$template"))
        {
            // extract variables into local scope
            extract($values);

            // render header
            require("../templates/header.php");

            // render template
            require("../templates/$template");

            // render footer
            require("../templates/footer.php");
        }

        // else err
        else
        {
            trigger_error("Invalid template: $template", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In which line? Why is the second part of your PHP code out of the PHP tags?

Comment: Dont you need to have all your code inside `<?php ?>`  tags?

Comment: Don't think you can create arrays like in python. Should you not use the `array` function?

Comment: `$x = [1,2]` type short-hand was introduced in PHP 5.4. You're probably running on 5.3 or earlier, where that particular syntax is a flat-out parse error.

Comment: @maksimov: python? Where's python in this question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Comment: @MarcB "like in python" i.e. simply [x, y].

Answer (score 3):

replace `render("home_form.php", ["title" => "Log In"]);`
with 
`render("home_form.php", array("title" => "Log In"));`
and

```
$values = []
```

with

```
$values = array()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That part is working. It throws other errors at places with [ character. I started changing all the codes with [] in them. But when i changed this function  function apologize($message)
    {
        render("apology.php", ["message" => $message]);
        exit;
    }   to  function apologize($message)
    {
        render("apology.php", ("message" => $message));
        exit;
    }  it throws this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /home/uenr/public_html/coun/includes/functions.php on line 19. Can you please help me to see the best way to deal with it?

Comment: you forgot to add array in front of a '(', i.e. array("message" => $message)

Answer (score 0):

Which PHP version do you use?

Short array syntax is available since PHP 5.4.0: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php